# Operator overloading problems

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the friends in a class definition obviously and to make it clearer, have removed the implementation code etc...

```
class Ref
{
    public:
        Ref(char* s, size_t l) : _s(s), _l(l) {}
    private:
        char* _s;
        size_t _l;
};

class foo
{
    public:
        friend stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream& s, uint8_t& v) { return s; }
        friend stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream& s, const Ref& r) { return s; }
    private:
        std::stringstream ss;
        void example(void)
        {
            char b[256];
            Ref r(b, sizeof(b));
            uint8_t i;

            ss >> i >> r;    <------ Why do I get an error here?
            ss >> r >> i;    <------ But this one seems to compile fine.
        }
};
```

Comment: You say your friends are in the class definition but in your code they are not. Which one is right, your statement or the code?

Comment: When asking about an error, **always** include the full error message.

Comment: After changing `l(_l)` to `_l(l)`, removing the `friend` keywords (since they can't appear outside a class definition) and changing `char* b[256]` to `char b[256]` and sticking the relevant code in a `main()`, this compiled just fine for me.

Comment: @GuyGreer Are you sure?  The results of `ss >> i` should be of type `std::istream`, and there's no `>>` for `istream >> Ref`.

Comment: @JamesKanze He had overloaded (in the global namespace) `operator>>` for `uint8_t` and `std::stringstream` to return a `std::stringstream &` and the compiler found that one before the one in `namespace std` in `<sstream>`.  After his edit, however, now this does not compile because this same overload is now in `class foo` the overload is never considered and the expected one in `<sstream>` is found through ADL.

Comment: @GuyGreer I'd missed that.  It's even worse than I thought, then, because he's trying to redefine operators which are already defined in the standard library.  (Frankly, it didn't even occur to me that someone would do this.)

Comment: @GuyGreer Which makes me wonder again about the code he's posting.  His examples are in a member function of `foo`, so his operators are always found.  For `ss >> i >> r`, his `>>` to `uint8_t` is an exact match, and so better than the one in the standard library, so it should be called.  And it returns an `std::stringstream&`, which should permit the following call.

Comment: @JamesKanze I believe that inside a member function the class you are in is in fact not automatically added to the set of considered possibilities.  This makes it necessary to add `this` to function calls inside member functions when `this` is a dependent name.  It also means that his `uint8_t` overload is not considered just because he's in a `foo` member function.  Note this is all prefaced with "I believe"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you overloading on `std::stringstream`?  You should
always be overloading on `std::istream` or `std::ostream`
(depending on the direction).  It's exceedingly rare that
`std::stringstream` would even be used (`std::istringstream` or
`std::ostringstream` would usually be more appropriate), and
even if they were, `operator>>` will normally return
a `std::istream&`, not a `std::stringstream&`.

EDIT:

With regards to why one seemed to work:

```
ss >> r >> i;
```

is

```
operator>>( operator>>( ss, r ), i );
```

You have defined an `operator>>` which takes a `stringstream&`
and `Ref const&`, so the inner call is valid.  And your
`operator>>` returns a `stringstream&`, which *isA*
`std::istream`, so the function `operator>>( std::istream&,
unsigned char )` can be called.  Where as:

```
ss >> i >> r;
```

is

```
operator>>( operator>>( ss, i ), r );
```

The inner call returns an `std::istream&`, and there is no
overloaded `operator>>` for `std::istream&, Ref const&`.

As stated above: overloaded `>>` should *always* take
`std::istream&` as there first argument, and return an
`std::istream&`.

Comment: perhaps you could comment on why his overload `friend stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream& s, uint8_t& v)` doesn't get called.

Comment: @GuyGreer Maybe because it isn't visible.  If he defined it in a class, then it can only be found with ADL, and ADL will only look in the namespace(s) the operator is in and in `std::` for something like `uint8_t`.  (But of course, my fundamental answer stands: you overload on `std::istream&`, and not on `std::stringstream`---a class I've never used.)

Comment: @GuyGreer And looking at his complete code: he's invoking the `>>` operator in a context where all of his `>>` will be found, so he'll get an ambiguous overload for `ss >> i`.

Comment: Agreed about the `std::istream&` and your answer, this was more for completeness, since the OP probably expected this overload to be found and used as well.

Comment: @GuyGreer That's the fun thing about ADL: sometimes you find it, sometimes you don't.  Depending on the context where he tried his two statements, one or the other would fail, for different reasons.

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for the comments, but the problem is...  I need a single stringstream that can have strings inserted and extracted and each string manipulated, converted and the result put into variables of different sizes and types...  hence the overloads.  I can't do that with just istream or istringstream.

Comment: @TheWelder I don't think you can do that with `stringstream` either.  At least if I understand you correctly; you can't insert into a `stringstream`, just overwrite existing text.  It is a stream, after all.  And even in the rare case where you need a `stringstream`, your overloaded operators should still use `std::istream` and `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ss >> i >> r;   <-------  why do I get an error here?
```

You forgot to tell us what the error is, or to post the actual code that gives you the error. When I fix the obvious errors in the posted code, I get:

```
cannot bind ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’
```

The first problem is that `ss >> i` won't call your overload; you can't overload the streaming operators for built-in types like `uint8_t`. So this will call the overload defined by the standard library, which returns a reference to `istream`, not `stringstream`.  Your operator expects a reference to `stringstream`, so the second operator will fail.

You should follow the convention and work with a generic `ostream` rather than a specific `stringstream`:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, const Ref& r) { return s; }
```

If you actually want the operator to do anything useful, then you'll need to remove the `const` from the second argument.

Comment: It's okay, the const is intentional because it's a temporary object and only it's internal methods are used by the operator and nothing is modified.